# Confusion while studying both Axler and Strang's Linear Algebra texts

Tags: linear-algebra

In Axler's text, we have a linear map $T : V \rightarrow W$, and the matrix of $T$ depends on the choices of bases for $V$ and $W$.

In Strang's text, we have a matrix $A$, and the linear map that it represents seems to change depending on what domain is considered.

Suppose $A$ is a $m$-by-$n$ matrix with rank $r$. If the domain is $\mathbb{R}^n$, then the dimension of $\text{range} A$ is $r$. However, consider the composition $AB$.

Would it be accurate to say that while $A$ used to represent the linear map $T : \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$, once composed with $B$, it now represents the linear map $T' : \text{range} B \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$?

To give some context, I'm trying to apply the Rank-Nullity Theorem to understand why
\begin{equation*}
 \dim \text{range} AB \leq \min(\dim \text{range} A, \dim \text{range} B),
\end{equation*}
and I don't know whether the dimension of the domain of $A$ is $n$ or $\dim \text{range} B$.

Answer (score 1):

Consider $AB$: the domain of $A$ is the image of $B$, when you take the product.

So, the image of $AB$ is contained in the image of $A$.  This gives one bound.

But, the image of $AB$ can't have higher dimension than the image of $B$, either (by the Rank-nullity theorem, linear transformations can't have higher rank than the dimension of their domain).